# https on magento Stackexchange broken

Tags: support

I noticed https on the magento Stackexchange shows a warning about unsecure connections. Reason seem to be http gravatar images.

the mata site is not even possible to access via https.

It is not reproducible with a clean browser (logged out state)

can someone reproduce this?

[image: https warning]

Comment: I can't reproduce it

Comment: I am getting the same thing here - partial encryption warning on magento.se.com and a full stop untrusted connection or connection not private error on meta.

Comment: The short answer is, unfortunately, we still don't fully support HTTPS. For more information, see [this old, sometimes-updated Meta SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) and the links there.